Alternatives to self assignment for 'breakpoint code'
I recently tried to build a project with clang and clang++. Up to now it has only been built with GCC.
One of the problems that I saw was with code that is of the following form
if (expression)
{
   var = var;
}

I assume that this was done to give a place in the code to put breakpoints in debug builds. In optimized builds the code should all be optimized away.
We build with -Werror and this fails to build with

error: explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'int' to itself [-Werror,-Wself-assign]

I can get rid of the warning/error with -Wno-self-assign or -Wno-error=self-assign or locally with
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wself-assign"
var = var;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

(possibly in a MACRO).
Does anyone have any other suggestions for code without side effects that could be used for breakpoints?

This is what I use.  It also issues an unused warning that make them easy to find.
int x = 3; 


But -Werror will turn the unused warning into an error, which is part of the OP's problem.

add a (void) x; to supress that.

The standard way in C++ is to use std::breakpoint or std::breakpoint_if_debugging() which is a new C++26 feature, the latter is probably more suitable

This function standardizes many similar existing facilities: __builtin_debugtrap from LLVM, __debugbreak from Win32 API, debugger_break from boost.test, assert(false), _asm { int 3 } (MSVC) and asm("int3") (GCC/clang) for x86 targets, etc.

#if DEBUG
if (std::is_debugger_present())
    std::breakpoint();
std::breakpoint_if_debugging();
#endif

As can be seen from the quote, in LLVM you can use __builtin_debugtrap, or if you have Boost you can use debugger_break
There are other methods that you can see in Is there a portable equivalent to DebugBreak()/__debugbreak?

I think the goal is to have a statement where you can set a breakpoint, but are not forced to.  With std::breakpoint the program will always stop when it is reached, and it doesn't go away on optimized builds.

@NateEldredge that's why I put an#if there. if (debug) {...} also works

But I think we want to be able to decide within the debugger whether to have a breakpoint there.

@NateEldredge yeah that's a valid concern. It's better to not use these at all though, because when we want to break at any line we should put a breakpoint manually at that line
